# could not be able to get correct result from sqlite query in android

Tags: android

I have tow tables named as `member` and `expense` and a `bridge` table which is used for join purpose, I want that `expense` should be equally divided into members which were partners in that `expense`

`UPDATE`

```
//Create Member table
CREATE TABLE member(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT);

// Create Expense table
CREATE TABLE expense (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, amount INTEGER, expenseItemName TEXT);

// Create Bridge Table
CREATE TABLE bridge( bridgeId, _id INTEGER FOREGIN KEY REFERENCES member( _id )  ON DELETE CASCADE, exp_id INTEGER FOREGIN KEY REFERENCES expense(_id)  ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

, I get the `count of present members` like this `MEMBER COUNT QUERY`

```
SELECT count(*) FROM member, expense, bridge WHERE expense._id = bridge.exp_id AND member._id = bridge._id GROUP BY expense._id
```

this gives me correct count of `members` present in `expense`, but when I want to divide `expense` into present members like this
`DIVIDE EXPENSE.AMOUNT QUERY`

```
SELECT expense._id, itemName, bridge._id, expense.amount/(SELECT count(*) FROM member, expense, bridge WHERE expense._id = bridge.exp_id AND member._id = bridge._id GROUP BY expense._id), (SELECT count(*) FROM member, expense, bridge WHERE expense._id = bridge.exp_id AND member._id = bridge._id GROUP BY expense._id) AS total_member, bridge.bridge_id FROM member, expense, bridge WHERE  (bridge._id = member._id  AND member._id = 2) AND expense._id = bridge.exp_id
```

using this query I get correct result for first `expense.amount`, but other records are not correct e.g If in `MEMBER COUNT QUERY` we get the result like `3,5`, then in `DIVIDE EXPENSE.AMOUNT QUERY` the `expense.amount` is only divided with `first` digit like `3` in this case. How to modify the `DIVIDE EXPENSE.AMOUNT QUERY` to divide `expense.amount` with all the digits like `3,5`in this case.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok on request I can provide full source code

Comment: Just proposed one solution. But I'm a little confused as to why you need the `bridge` table. Can items in your `expense` table be shared by more than one item in `member`? If not, you can just have `member` and `expense` and add the `member_id` to your `expense` table.

Comment: yes  items in `expense` table be shared by more than one item in member.

Comment: Arshad, did you check my edited answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT expense._id, itemName, bridge._id, expense.amount/
    (SELECT count(*) 
    FROM expense as E2, bridge as B2
    WHERE E2._id = B2.exp_id
        AND B2._id = M._id), 
    (SELECT count(*) 
    FROM expense as E2, bridge as B2
    WHERE E2._id = B2.exp_id
        AND B2._id = M._id) AS total_member, 
    bridge.bridge_id 
FROM member as M, expense as E, bridge as B
WHERE  (B._id = M._id  AND M._id = 2) 
    AND E._id = B.exp_id
```

UPDATE 1:

Come to think of it, I'm not sure sqlite supports this kind of subquery. Try this instead:

```
SELECT E._id, itemName, B._id, E.amount/table_count.count,
    table_count.count AS total_member, 
    B.bridge_id 
FROM member as M, expense as E, bridge as B,
    (SELECT B2._id as b2_id, count(*) as count
        FROM expense as E2, bridge as B2
        WHERE E2._id = B2.exp_id
        GROUP BY B2._id) as table_count
WHERE  (B._id = M._id  AND M._id = 2) 
    AND E._id = B.exp_id 
    AND table_count.b2_id = m._id
```

UPDATE 2:

Trying again, this time I created a test schema so perhaps you can play a bit with the solution I'm giving below. Hope it works this time:

```
SELECT E._id, expenseItemName, B._id, E.amount, 
    table_count.count AS total_member,
    E.amount/table_count.count
FROM member as M, expense as E, bridge as B,
    (SELECT B2.exp_id as b2_exp_id, count(*) as count
        FROM expense as E2, bridge as B2
        WHERE E2._id = B2.exp_id
        GROUP BY B2.exp_id) as table_count
WHERE  (B._id = M._id  AND M._id = 2) 
    AND E._id = B.exp_id 
    AND table_count.b2_exp_id = E._id
```

You can try this here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/aeca2/13 But you need Chrome or SQLite. I modified a bit your schema but I hope you can get the picture and make the small changes needed to your case.

Comment: Try my edited answer if it works. If it doesn't, please provide the details so I can try to help you further.

Comment: please see my `UPDATE`, if that makes sense for you?

Comment: @ArshadAliSoomro Hi, I just proposed another solution above. Check out also the link where you can play with the query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/aeca2/13

Comment: Man it worked as I desired, I have no words to say you thanks, but you have done a good job for me and ya it helped me, After all `I thank You`!

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad it worked out in the end. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Multipile `expense.amount` by 1.0 may do the tricks. Here is the sql

```
`SELECT expense._id, itemName, bridge._id, expense.amount * 1.0 /(SELECT count(*) FROM member, expense, bridge WHERE expense._id = bridge.exp_id AND member._id = bridge._id GROUP BY expense._id), (SELECT count(*) FROM member, expense, bridge WHERE expense._id = bridge.exp_id AND member._id = bridge._id GROUP BY expense._id) AS total_member, bridge.bridge_id FROM member, expense, bridge WHERE  (bridge._id = member._id  AND member._id = 2) AND expense._id = bridge.exp_id
`
```

Hope this help.